# Xamarin, Update existing app from within the app. Without any services. App not installed error when updating. Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to update the app from within installed app Android.

I have my .NET 5 Web Api link which starts a download of the updated app. After the download is ended my app runs instance of the downloaded APK and opens installation/update window.  [image] [image]

Then I hit install and it shows the error "**App not installed.**".

[image]

As I understood it right(?), the error occurs because it sees the same application in the system installed. Although the **downloaded APK has different** versionCode & versionName(`in this case for example, I run versionCode=3 & versionName=3.0 APK, FROM versionCode=2 & versionName=2.0`). **I didn't change any names or any other data** except versionName and versionCode.

[image]

So what can I do? Maybe I missed important information about versioning? I have searched through whole internet and stuck on the last step.

Comment: Check device log to see what the exact error is. `adb logcat` and observe the log when you install.

Comment: Also I recommend that you use PackageInstaller API instead of using intents: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller it will tell you about issues much sooner. It is most likely something like signing signature differs from the installed one or something like that, but unclear until you actually check the device log...

Comment: @Cheesebaron thank you for your reply. Is this the reason?: Package ... signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

Comment: Sure looks like it. So the version you are running on device, probably through debug is signed with a debug signing key. You will need to sign the App you are trying to install with the same keystore.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thatk you a lot. That was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was because of not matching keystore(Keystore which you create when distributing an app), debug session app does not have any as I understand. Basically I was trying to install an update from debug session. After I created apk through Archive in visual studio with version 2, installed it on the emulator(removed all instances of the app on the emulator beforehand), my update installed successfully.